# Shell script to increment a value inside a python script

Tags: python, shell

I have a simple python script which I'd like to write a shell script to increase a specific value (bearer_id) inside the script incrementally (till a fixed value like 100, 200) and repeat the other lines just as they are (example below). can you please give me some hints/or example of a shell script, on how to do this?

script.py is like:

```
sgw.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=1, \
saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10", \
sport_ingress=2152)
```

Final script should be like this, script.py:

```
sgwumgt.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=1, \
saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10", \
sport_ingress=2152)

sgwumgt.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=2, \
saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10", \
sport_ingress=2152)
.
.#repeat 99 times
.
sgwumgt.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=100, \
saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10", \
sport_ingress=2152)
```

p.s: This has to be a separate shell script which I execute it over ssh on the remote machine (which has this python script, ready to execute) then this shell script must either create a new .py file such as I mentioned above or change the existing one in that way for further steps.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why not just do all of this within python?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've heard of a loop. I recommend going through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/); it'll answer this question and a whole lot more.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of the loop concept :) The explanation may haven't been clear enough, This has to be a separate shell script which I execute it over ssh on the remote machine (which has this python script, ready to execute) then this shell script must either create a new .py file such as I mentioned above or change the existing one in that way for further steps. sorry again for my not clear explanation

Comment: edited the question :)

Comment: You want to write code that rewrites your other code? That... doesn't sound like the best way to accomplish your underlying goal. Also, even if you use a script-rewriting script, you should probably make it write a loop.

Comment: Kinda yes, I know this sounds  a bit strange, but this .py script is on the remote machine (will be back to the default state after I finished and rebooted the server) and the only way to accomplish this goal is to execute a shell script to rewrite that .py script in that way (just to be executed once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing that is changing is the bearer_id than you could use a for loop instead

Something like:

```
for id in range(1,101):
    sgw.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=id, \
    saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10", \
    sport_ingress=2152)
```

This would greatly reduce the amount of code you needed to write as well as make it easier to modify the code later.

Comment: You don't need the backslash at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Looping constructs exist to solve this exact problem you have:

```
max_id = 100
for id in range(1, max_id+1):
    sgwumgt.add_bearer(dpid=256, bearer_id=id,
                       saddr_ingress="10.1.1.10",
                       sport_ingress=2152)
```

If you weren't aware you could do this then you really should spend some time with some python tutorials as this is a very fundamental building block for writing python code.

If the python script has to change the behavior based on a command line parameter you have a few options. You can use `argparse` or similar or perhaps do something quick with `sys.argv`. Here's a way you can do this with `sys.argv`:

```
import sys
if(len(sys.argv)) == 1:
    max_id == 100 #Default case
elif(len(sys.argv)) == 2:
    max_id = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Which you can then call on the command line with `python script.py 150` which would set `max_id` to 150. If you need to do more complex argument parsing I would recommend using `argparse`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the loop concept :) The explanation may haven't been clear enough, This has to be a separate shell script which I execute it over ssh on the remote machine (which has this python script, ready to execute) then this shell script must either create a new .py file such as I mentioned above or change the existing one in that way for further steps. sorry again for my not clear explanation

Comment: Can you have your python script take a command line argument and call that from the shell?

Comment: I don't think so(actually not sure at the moment), it's better to rewrite a new copy of that .py script in that way. don't have access to remote machine till next two hours. I'll check it ASAP

Comment: It seems like I just don't understand your use case. You can make a new `.py` file from a shell script but you cannot modify an existing `.py` file?

Comment: yes, exactly! I can just read it. there's no write access for that .py script

Comment: Honestly I think you should reconsider your setup here because it's extremely strange that you can generate a python file that you can execute but can't actually just write that file out in the first place. Say you can store a shell script you can always just echo out the python script then run that. But I just can't see a sensible situation where you can run a shell script that creates a python script that then runs the recently created python script. I can't see why you don't change your approach to use only a python script the entire way.

Comment: I know it really looks strange, but I've been told this morning that I'm supposed to use this approach (shell script) for this goal, that's the reason why nothing came into my mind first...
I'll find access to this remote machine in less than two hours, let me check to see if I can use the python script as a solution or not, will come back again. Thanks a lot for your time and effort! :)